# json accept single value as array

Tags: c#, .net, json

How to json accept single value as array?

This json throw exception:

> {
>        "code": "1",
>        "message": "OK",
>        "response": {
>           "partners": 
>               {
>                   "id": "33",
>                   "name": "",
>                   "clienttypeid": "29",
>                   "logo": "",
>                   "description": "",
>                   "website": "www.site.com"
>               }
>           }
>       }

This json parsed correct:

> {
>       "code": "1",
>       "message": "OK",
>       "response": {
>           "partners": [
>               {
>                   "id": "33",
>                   "name": "",
>                   "clienttypeid": "29",
>                   "logo": "",
>                   "description": "",
>                   "website": "www.site.com"
>               },
>               {
>                   "id": "34",
>                   "name": "",
>                   "clienttypeid": "29",
>                   "logo": "",
>                   "description": "",
>                   "website": "www.site.com"
>               }
>           ]
>       } }

Model:

```
public class Partner
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string clienttypeid { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Partner> partners { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to deserialize to a `List`, use array notation, even with one element

```
{
    "code":"1",
    "message":"OK",
    "response":{
        "partners":[
            {
                "id":"33",
                "name":"",
                "clienttypeid":"29",
                "logo":"",
                "description":"",
                "website":"www.site.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Server not returned array notation [...] if value is single

Answer (score 2):

I used [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to convert the `partners` to array if it is a single object

```
string Normalize(string json)
{
    var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
    if (!(jobj["response"]["partners"] is JArray))
    {
        jobj["response"]["partners"] = new JArray(jobj["response"]["partners"]);
    }
    return jobj.ToString();
}
```